# Excel export using PHPExcel inserting ? characters

Tags: php, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I am trying to export data to `.xls` format using PHPExcel. This is the code I am using

```
require_once "excel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT oc_product.product_id,oc_product.model,oc_product.price,oc_product_description.name FROM oc_product LEFT JOIN oc_product_description ON oc_product_description.product_id=oc_product.product_id");
$product_data = $query->rows;
$objTpl = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("excel/template.xls");
$objTpl->setActiveSheetIndex(0);  
$i=3;

foreach ($product_data as $prod) 
{
    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i, $prod['product_id']);
    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$i, $prod['name']);
    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$i, $prod['model']);
    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$i, $prod['price']);
    $i++;
}

$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);  

$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(40);  
$filename=mt_rand(1,100000).'.xls'; //just some random filename
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objTpl, 'Excel5');  
$objWriter->save('php://output');  
exit;
```

The file get downloaded fine but when I open the file it shows '?' after every letter like this "?D?O?U?B?L?E? ?F?A?C?E? ?S?H?E?E?T?S?.??".

Comment: What is the charset for your database table? What charset for the connection to the database? And you need to ensure that the data you're setting in your cells is utf-8?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is related to character encoding. Try adding this header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

it will force char encoding; your output seems to be a 16bit encoding (like unicode or utf16), using two bytes (char), the first one is filled with a '?'

ADD:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

will force char encoding in the SQL query output

Comment: No dude getting same response.

Comment: try adding `$query = $this->db->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");` before the `SELECT`; another test could be to open the .xls with another program, like Libreoffice or Openoffice